# Is it okay for two columns to be created in a bidirectional relationship?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Is it possible to create one column for bi-directional relationship?

My Entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "subscription")
@Proxy(lazy = false)
public class Subscription {

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "subscription_id")
private long id;

@Column(name = "userid", nullable = false)
private String userId;

@Column(name = "saledate", nullable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date saleDate;

@Column(name = "finishdate", nullable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date finishDate;

@Column(name = "price", nullable = false)
private long price;

@Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
private String description;


@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "subscription")
private List<VisitDate> visitDates = new ArrayList<>();
}



@Entity
@Table(name="visitdate")

public class VisitDate {
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private long id;
private long subscription;

@Column(name = "date", nullable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date date;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="subscription_id")
private Subscription associatedSub;
}
```

Now I see two columns in the database and little bit confused.

I don't want to save the same data but want to display a report about how many users visit on some day.

**Update:**

[image]

Comment: you mean 1 FK column in the element table? That is what you get when you have 1 PK column, yes

Comment: @BillyFrost yes, I have 2 Foreign Keys . And Nothing can do for this case?

Comment: If your JPA provider is creating 2 FK COLUMNs instead of 1 then kindly post your schema, and indicate which column you have a problem with

Comment: @BillyFrost I uploaded schema. Column subscription and subscription_id have same date. Thay link to subscription id from subscription table

Comment: And? You added an extra field to your class for some reason so you get what you should expect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not required to create a separate field "subscription" in VisitDate class. Hibernate will automatically create a field to store subscription id. The code needs to be slightly changed.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "subscription")
public class Subscription {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "subscription_id")
  private long id;

  @Column(name = "userid", nullable = false)
  private String userId;

  @Column(name = "saledate", nullable = false)
  @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
  private Date saleDate;

  @Column(name = "finishdate", nullable = false)
  @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
  private Date finishDate;

  @Column(name = "price", nullable = false)
  private long price;

  @Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
  private String description;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "associatedSub")
  private List<VisitDate> visitDates = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Notice, that I have changed the mappedBy property to point at associatedSub in the above class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="visitdate")

public class VisitDate {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private long id;

  @Column(name = "date", nullable = false)
  @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
  private Date         date;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="subscription_id")
  private Subscription associatedSub;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Uni-Directional relationship for the same purpose. You just need to add a list/set of Visits for a particular subscription, You don't have to create a list of subscription for a particular visit.
for reference Visit [Java JPA] :(https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany#Undirectional_OneToMany.2C_No_Inverse_ManyToOne.2C_No_Join_Table_.28JPA_2.0_ONLY.29)!

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "subscription")
@Proxy(lazy = false)
public class Subscription {

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "subscription_id")
private long id;

@Column(name = "userid", nullable = false)
private String userId;

@Column(name = "saledate", nullable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date saleDate;

@Column(name = "finishdate", nullable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date finishDate;

@Column(name = "price", nullable = false)
private long price;

@Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
private String description;


@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "subscription")
private List<VisitDate> visitDates = new ArrayList<>();
}



@Entity
@Table(name="visitdate")

public class VisitDate {
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private long id;

private long subscription;

@Column(name = "date", nullable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date date;
}
```